# How can I remove argument redundancy with lists of similar arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having trouble removing some redundancy in a series of C++ logging functions. They are each variants that alter on the first parameter, and the form of the final parameters.  I'm thinking somehow a variant with a variadic template might help.

The two basic functions:

```
void error( util::source_provider const & where, std::string const & reason )
void error( util::source_location const & where, std::string const & reason )
```

The first argument differs between a `source_provider` and `source_location`. These are basic structs, no virtuals.  After the `reason` I have several functions that look like these (with both the location and provider version):

```
void error( util::source_provider const & where, std::string const & reason,
    std::vector<item> const & itemsA, 
    std::vector<item> const & itemsB,
    boost::optional<item> item0 = boost::optional<item>(),
    boost::optional<item> item1 = boost::optional<item>() )
void error( util::source_provider const & where, std::string const & reason,
    std::vector<item> const & itemsA,
    boost::optional<item> item0 = boost::optional<item>(),
    boost::optional<item> item1 = boost::optional<item>() )
void error( util::source_provider const & where, std::string const & reason,
    boost::optional<item> item0 = boost::optional<item>(),
    boost::optional<item> item1 = boost::optional<item>() )
```

I'm trying to make it convenient for the caller to provide lists of these `item` entries in whatever form they have. The information comes from a variety of places and it'd be an explosion of syntax at the call site if they needed to assemble into a single list. Some of this is also added via macros calling the logger.

What combination of features do I use to reduce this? I'm guessing I need a vardiac template with a variant somehow, to accept either a vector or item.

For clarity, these functions all ultimately call this function, combining all the `item` args into one vector first:

```
virtual void error_impl( boost::optional<util::source_location> where, std::string const & reason,
        std::vector<item> const & items ) = 0;
```

*C++14 is okay. I'm using GCC 5.4 so I don't think all of C++17 is available yet.*

Comment: Are implementation identical ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Close. I added the target `error_impl` function. They all collect their arguments into a single vector and call `error_impl` with one vector.

Comment: How about passing an `initializer_list`?

Comment: I would use a helper class to deal with the first parameter, with the helper class constructible from a reference to either a `util::source_provider` or a `util::source_location`. That would deal with the first parameter. Then variadic pack to vacuum up the remaining parameters.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah right, got short-sighted there. Somehow forgot I can simply create my own helper that implicity converts from all the types I need for the first parameter.